# MVC Autocomplete fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering why the label field is being replaced by the value once I choose from the list of autocomplete:

Script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("#Users").autocomplete({source: function(request,response) 
 {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/AutoCompleteUsers",
        type: "POST",dataType: "json",
        data: { term: request.term },
        success: function (data) {
             response($.map(data, function (item) {
               return { label:item.Name, value:item.ID };
             }))
         }
       })
     },
     select: function (event, ui){
          $("#Employees").val(ui.item.label);
          $("#EmployeeID").val(ui.item.value);
     },messages: {noResults: "", results: ""} 
   });
});
```

Form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Show","Home", FormMethod.Post)){

    @Html.TextBox("Employees")
    <input id="EmployeeID" type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

It shows the corresponding ID of each name but the textbox has been replaced by the value in EmployeeID field. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the documentation of jquery autocomplete:

> ... An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
>   The label property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The value will be inserted into the input element when a user selects an item. If just one property is specified, it will be used for both, e.g., if you provide only value properties, the value will also be used as the label.

If you do not want this behaviour, one way would be to just return the label:

```
{return { item.Name };
```

But this would then give you problems in the "select" event, since you need the ID there.

So perhaps this would be better:

```
$("#Users").autocomplete({
    source: function(request,response) 
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/AutoCompleteUsers",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { term: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return { label:item.Name, value:item.ID };
                }))
            }
        })
    },
    select: function (event, ui){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#Employees").val(ui.item.label);
        $("#EmployeeID").val(ui.item.value);
    },
    messages: {noResults: "", results: ""} 
});
```

This will update "Employees" with the label/name and "EmployeeID" with the value/id. You have the autocomplete bound to "Users", and this should not be updated at all using this code.

Comment: So how would it be possible to get the the label field as well as the value field? Do you have any idea for this Sir? Thanks